# Generating UML-like block diagram in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to create UML-like block diagram with connected components dynamically in Silverlight. How to do this? What controls should be used for this? It is required to add show/hide toggle for some items in the blocks.

Comment: this is not a simple task---look here: http://michaelsync.net/2011/09/22/silverlight-diagram-editor

Comment: But, my figures are fairly static apart from the show/hide toggle.

Comment: as side comment, while SL is surely powerful is not fully cross platform and requires the plugin to be installed. Google docs requires no plugin and works in all browsers and platforms, they have recently released a presentation tool powerpoint like with similar features to those shown in the SL diagrams linked above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ItemsControl with a Canvas.

```
namespace SlBug1
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    public partial class UML : UserControl
    {
        public UML()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetupData();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public object Classes { get; set; }
        public object Arrows { get; set; }

        #region Set up data

        public void SetupData()
        {

            var arrows = new List<Arrow>(

                new Arrow[] {
                    new Arrow(50, 250, 200, 250),
                    new Arrow(50, 50, 200, 220)
                }
            );

            this.Arrows = arrows;

            var classes = new List<Class>(
                new Class[]
                {
                    new Class { Name = "Line", Methods= new string[] { "Draw", "setColor"} , X=10, Y=11, IsExpanded=true},
                    new Class { Name = "Rectangle", Methods = new string[] { "Draw", "setColor", "setFill"}, X=200, Y=200, IsExpanded=true},
                    new Class { Name = "Circle", Methods = new string[] {"Draw", "setColor", "setFill", "setRadius"}, X=10, Y=200, IsExpanded=false},
                });

            this.Classes = classes;

        }

        #endregion

    }

    public class Class
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Methods { get; set; }

        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    }

    public class Arrow
    {
        public Arrow(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2)
        {
            this.X1 = X1; this.Y1 = Y1;
            this.X2 = X2; this.Y2 = Y2;
        }

        public double X1 { get; set; }
        public double Y1 { get; set; }
        public double X2 { get; set; }
        public double Y2 { get; set; }
        public double LX1 { get { return (14 * X2 + X1) / 15; } }
        public double RX1 { get { return (14 * X2 + X1) / 15; } }
        public double LY1 { get { return (14 * Y2 + Y1) / 15 - 10; } }
        public double RY1 { get { return (14 * Y2 + Y1) / 15 + 10; } }
    }
}

    <UserControl x:Class="SlBug1.UML"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <Canvas>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ArrowsCanvas" ItemsSource="{Binding Arrows}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Line X1="{Binding X1}" X2="{Binding X2}"
                                  Y1="{Binding Y1}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" Stroke="Black" />
                            <Line X1="{Binding LX1}" X2="{Binding X2}"
                                  Y1="{Binding LY1}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" Stroke="Black" />
                            <Line X1="{Binding RX1}" X2="{Binding X2}"
                                  Y1="{Binding RY1}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" Stroke="Black" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="UmlCanvas" ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Hack: http://forums.silverlight.net/post/370493.aspx -->
                        <Canvas>
                            <Border Background="LightBlue"
                            Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"
                            Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"
                            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" >
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" />
                                    <ItemsControl 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Methods}" 
                                        Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The end result looks something like this:

[image: UML diagram - pardon me for the brain-dead inheritance]

Comment: At least use the arrows from the Blend SDK.  There's no need to rewrite an arrow class.

Answer (score 1):

See this post here: [C# .NET Document Based Application manipulating Diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186293/c-sharp-net-document-based-application-manipulating-diagrams/8513926#8513926)

It talks about java/WPF diagramming options. I think that the link I suggested in that article (*[WPF Diagram Designer - Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)*) is a very strong contender for starting you off. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [GoXam](http://www.goxam.com) to be a pretty nice product.  It's not cheap, but it's pretty well constructed and will handle this task very well. It also includes built in layout packages so your diagrams can be made to look pretty.

edit: There's a 30 day trial for it.  Check out the ER Diagram sample online -- it's probably pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just css+javascript ? If i'm not mistaken you can generate/embed html inside silverlight.

Comment: You are mistaken. It is not possible to display HTML in a Silverlight 4 browser based application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MiniUML](http://miniuml.codeplex.com/). This client WPF, but I think that you can adapt it to yourself

Answer (score 0):

We use [DiagramLite](http://www.mindfusion.eu/diagramlite.html) from MindFusion extensively for this sort of application. It works extremely well and is reasonably priced.

Answer (score 0):

Check this product

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/silverlight/diagram

Hope it suits your requirement.